# Redirect to login when session cookie expires in Django

Tags: python, django, session, cookies

I'm trying to redirect to the login page when the cookie expires but it's not working.

It's supposed to be as simple as adding these lines to settings.py:

```
LOGIN_URL = '/login/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL='/login/'
```

I'm using the decorator *@login_required* in my functions and I have tried *@login_required(login_url='/login/')* too.

Urls are correctly set and when manually going to /login it works, so it's not an error in the path.

When the session cookie expires and you try to access the app it gives you the error 'ViewDoesNotExist' (Could not import django.views.generic.simple.redirect_to. Parent module django.views.generic.simple does not exist.).

Comment: Something in your code is trying to import `redirect_to`, which was removed in Django 1.5. If you include the full traceback in your question, it will show where the problem is. How are you importing `login_required`? Which version of Django are you using?

Comment: And please add your code in views.py

Comment: I can't believe it was this, I thought it was giving this error because he couldn't find the view due to login. If you can add it as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: Would there be a way of redirecting to login even if there was an error? Like catching the error and redirecting.

Comment: A server error means there is somthing wrong with your code. When your code raises an unhandled exception, Django will display a 500 error page and email the site admins. You shouldn't normally need to override `handler500`, and you certainly shouldn't try to redirect it to the login page. Instead, you should fix the code that raised the unhandled exception. In this case, you have old, out of date code that is trying to use `redirect_to`. Since you haven't shown that code or the traceback, we can't help any more than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something in your code is trying to import `redirect_to`, which was removed in Django 1.5. You need to find this code and update it.